# What is the difference between the equality operator and deepEquals in go?

Tags: go

After reading [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators), I have got:

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

This implies to me that doing `structA == structB` would mean that the values of each non-blank field in the struct would have `fieldA == fieldB` applied to it.  So why do we need a concept of a deep equals? Because if the struct has fields which are also structs, the information provided implies to me that those fields will be checked for equality using `==` also, so surely that would trigger traversal down the object graph anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing that you are missing is pointers. When doing a `==` on pointer, should you check the pointer value (two memory addresses) or the pointed value (two vars) ? And when comparing slices, or maps (both of which can be assimilated to a struct made of pointers) ?

The decision of golang's authors was to do a strict comparison with the `==` operator, and to provide the `reflect.DeepEqual` method for those that want to compare the content of their slices.

I personnally make an extensive use of `reflect.DeepEquals` in tests, as the output value of a function may be a pointer, but waht I really want to compare is the content of the output value.